# How to temporarily persist extra form parameters after presence validation failure in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have a new action that shows a form with most of my User models attributes, with the exception of some checkboxes (schools and roles through join tables). If some presence validation fails I am redirected back to the new action with the pre filled values. Except since the User model does not have those extra checkbox parameters it just remains empty. I need to be able to pre fill those values if the user is redirected due to presence validation being false. It seems a redirect happens and not a render, so I cannot access the `params[:school_id]` or `params[:role_id]` arrays of checked values by the user before the error. The quickest and dirty way to fix this would be to temporarily store the values in the session, then removing them upon redirecting. Seems wrong though. Is there a right way to do this?

**User Model**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # These validate filters cause the create code to never run if the presence is false.
  # Because of this I cannot persist the parameters passed into params[:school_id] and params[:role_id]
  validates :fName, presence: true
  validates :lName, presence: true
  validates :title, presence: true
  validates :phone, presence: true
  # ...
```

**User controller**

```
# Registration
def new
    @user = User.new()
end

# Register
def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save()
        join_school_and_users(@user) # Joins the school with user using params[:school_id]
        join_roles_and_users(@user) # joins the role with the user using params[:role_id]
        redirect_to users_path, notice: 'User successfully added.'
    else
        render action: 'new', notice: 'Failed to create your user.'
    end

end
```

Comment: what you are writing does not make sense. if the model could not be saved, you will render and not redirect.

Comment: @phoet My User model has the `validates` filter. If there is a validation error my controller code never runs. I will add that part of my User model. But thats my problem. I need a way to be able to persist the checkboxes.The join... methods actually use the extra parameters.But since that code never runs, I never get a chance to render instead of redirecting and persisting that info.

Comment: i don't understand that. whatever code you have in those methods, please post it.

Comment: @phoet those methods never run. There is no point to paste them. All they do is access `params[:school_id]` or `params[:role_id]` which holds an array of ids for those checkboxes. I added my User model.

Comment: `It seems a redirect happens and not a render,` => why?

Comment: Because `params[]` is empty when I try to access it after the `validates` filter sends me back to the new action to show the form. If it rendered it, shouldn't I be able to access what was in params before?

Comment: that is no reason, it's just a symptom.